# Issue with Routes in Angular Js

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm starting to develop a web application using Angular Js as frontend. This application calls some rest services that are deployed into a jboss application server (installed locally).
My idea is to have a single page application with a fix header, then some dinamic content that is changing according to the routes and finally a fix footer.
I'm using ng-view to achieve this and the html code of this page looks like this:

```
    <div id="container" class="container">

        <div id="header" ng-include="'partials/header/header.html'" ></div>
        <div ng-view></div>
        <div id="footer" ng-include="'partials/footer/footer.html'"></div>

    </div>
```

In the configution phase, I set up the routes of the application like this just to test that everything is working as expected:

```
var myApp = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {

$routeProvider.
    when('/home', {
        templateUrl: '/partials/content/home.html',
        controller: 'appController'
    }).
    when('/register', {
        templateUrl: '/partials/content/register.html',
        controller: 'appController'
    }).
    when('/contact', {
        templateUrl: '/partials/content/contact.html',
        controller: 'appController'
    }).
    otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/home'
    });
  }]);
```

And then, in the header.html I have a topbar with some buttons to switch between the different views.

```
<div class="header">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
                <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#register">Register</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
            <h3 class="text-muted">Arena Club</h3>
</div>
```

Defining the routes this way is working fine. When I access the application with the request ("localhost:9000"), the application is redirecting automatically to "localhost:9000/#/home",
so when the page is loaded by the first time , ng-view is loading home.html by default (I guess because of the .otherwise clause), then if I click in any of the button of my top bar, the view is updated accordingly, which is the behaviour I expect.

However, now I want to go an step further and get rid of this static declaration of the routes on the client side and instead, get all the routes from the server (this way in the future, once I have users with different roles, routes will be more dinamic depending on the role of the user).
To achieve that, I store all the routes with their correspondent controllers into a Json file and in the configuration phase I do an Ajax call using Jquery (as the angular services are not ready yet in the phase) to call a rest service that is retrieving the json data from the server.

So basically, in my app.js I have replaced the old code by this new code, which, in my opinion, should get the same result:

```
var myApp = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {

$.ajax({url:'http://localhost:8080/arenaclub/rest/menuservice/topbar'}).done(function(data)
        {

            for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
            {
                $routeProvider.
                    when(data[i].path, {
                        templateUrl: data[i].templateUrl,
                        controller: data[i].controller
                    });
            }
            $routeProvider.otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/home'
        });


        });


}]);
```

And here is how my topbarmenu.json looks like:

```
{
   "menuid" : "topbar",
   "items" : [
        {
      "title" : "Home",
      "position" : "left",
      "path" : "/home",
      "templateUrl":"partials/content/home.html",
      "controller" : "appController"
  }, {
  "title" : "Register",
  "position" : "right",
  "path" : "/register",
  "templateUrl":"partials/content/register.html",
  "controller" : "appController"

},  {
  "title" : "Contact",
  "position" : "right",
  "path" : "/contact",
  "templateUrl":"partials/content/contact.html",
  "controller" : "appController"

     }]
}
```

The rest call is working fine and when I debug it using Chrome I can see that the object "data" has the right information so the routes are configured properly.

However, when I start now the application and I do the first request ("localhost:9000"), the application is no longer redirecting automatically to "localhost:9000/#/home". Instead, it remains as "localhost:9000" and therefore the ng-view is not loading home.html by default. 
Of course if I click on any of the buttons, the associated view is loaded properly and the urls in the browser are updated accordingly, but I want to have this home.html loaded by default instead of having to click on the button to display it. 
I don't understand why I have lost the initial behaviour, what I'm doing wrong? Do you see that I'm missing something?

In my opinion declaring the routes like this should lead to the same behaviour as declaring them completely statically, but I'm clearly missing something our doing something wrong. Please any help , suggestion , workaround would be really apreciated as I'm a bit blocked here.

Thank you very much in advance!!!

Comment: Loading the router config from ajax is not correct way...angularjs core not understanding and it is not waiting for capturing the configuration till ajax completed.

Comment: So what's the way to achieve what I want?Or there is no way? I can only get the data from the server using an Ajax call as in the configuration phase because angular services such as $http are not created yet during this phase.